# Java script listens to a port number which is bind by a java http server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know we can not write any socket programming using normal java script as those are the client side codes. It is possible to create server that bind to a port using node. js. But I do not need those. One of my complex requirement is that I have java http server running in  my machine which bind to a port number 7878.
When the java server is started, I want the client code which is running in my browser should get notify that the server is started. 
Is it practically possible?? 
Or is it possible for node. js or any js framework which will be running in the client side code and listens to the port number 7878.and when the java server is started it will get notified. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions/solutions.

Comment: if http is all you have you could just do a http request every couple of seconds. It will fail until the server is up.

Comment: You could definitely do it with Node/Express + socket.io. When your server loads up, fire an HTTP request to your node instance, which will send a message to your web app.

Comment: Sorry to mention that I have started a java https server which uses a self sign certificate. @toksv I know initially I was doing the same by sending an http request. But when I implemented https server and when I am sending the https request from java script it always fail because the certificate is self signed. The idea is if by any way if java script knows the server started then from Clent side code I will invoke a browser pop-up showing the url http://localhost:7878 and the user will accept the certificate and then the https request will be called.